# Get the concrete class for the value of an interface-typed variable

Tags: c#, templates, interface

Okay I am not sure how to word this so I apologize up front.

I have...

```
public interface Ifoo
{
     string commonFunc();
}

public class fiz : Ifoo
{
     public string commonFunc() { /*...*/ }
}

public class buzz : Ifoo
{
     public string commonFunc() { /*...*/ }
}
```

Each fizz and buzz also have numerous other properties that are specific to that class, and in rare cases I need to access those functions/members...

```
Ifoo temp = new buzz();
(buzz)tmp.privatemember;
```

one such case I came across is for error logging, if something goes wrong, I want to grab the ID and a few other properties if available on each. but to do that I need the base type of the object... Because I am working in generics I would rather not have to copy and paste a lot of my functionality just to cast the value in the specific case.

So my big question is. **Is there any way to get the base class templated in the interface**

EG.

```
//interface contains T getClass();
//fizz and buzz respectivly have a 
public fizz getClass(){
    return  (fizz)this;
}
```

or am I completely wrong on my logic here...

Comment: You can't instantiate interface. `new Ifoo()`  isn't legal for compiler.

Comment: Edited title to add clarity to what's being asked.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan good point I will reword that, I actually use them in collections,. such as ICollection<Ifoo> tmp = new List<Ifoo>();

Comment: So how do you add items to this collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. No matter what, to get derived type-specific properties, you *have* to downcast.

Even using generics doesn't solve this problem, since generics are strongly typed at compile time, you have to declare the type when using them.

A **much** simpler solution would be to add a function like this to `IFoo`:

```
string GetLogDetails()
```

And then override it in each derived class. With that, each class can return the correct logging information in string form, and whatever is invoking the method can aggregate all the information together.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to just get if a given IFoo is either fizz or buzz?

To do that, you can simply do a check such as:

```
IFoo x = ..

if(x is fizz) {
    fizz fizzX = (fizz)x;

    // do fizz stuff

} else if (x is buzz) {
    buzz buzzX = (buzz)x;

    // do buzz stuff

}
```